# Is there a better way on validating a password?

Tags: python

I'm checking my password for this criteria

1. be at least 10 characters long
2. contain at least 1 capital letter
3. contain at least 1 number
4. contain at least one of the characters $, #, %, &, or *
5. not contain any spaces

my code:

```
password = input("enter a password ")
def passwordIsOk (password):
    symbols = "$#%&*"
    if len (password) > 10:
        if any(i.isupper() for i in password):
            if any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
                if " " not in password:
                    for i in range(0,5):
                        if symbols[i] in password:
                            passwordValid = True
                            if passwordValid == True:
                                print("ok buddy")
                            else:
                                print("Password must contain $#%&*")
                else:
                    print("Password must not contain spaces")
            else:
                print("Password must have at least 1 number")
        else:
            print("Password must have at least 1 capital letter")
    else:
        print("Password must be greater than 10 characters")
passwordIsOk(password)
```

It works, but It just don't feel right :(

Comment: Why not make it as series of independent `if` statements instead of this crazy ladder of nested ones?

Comment: Please post this as full, runnable code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) instead. This is quite broad for SO.

Comment: Are you sure it works? If you type `Abcdefgh1#` it will tell you "Password must contain $#%&*" and then "ok buddy"

Comment: Passwords are also often checked for similarity to username.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this kind of nested `if` structure by inverting the conditions. This makes the code much more readable, and puts the error messages next to the conditions which check for those errors.

```py
def passwordIsOk(password):
    symbols = "$#%&*"
    if len (password) <= 10:
        print("Password must be greater than 10 characters")
    elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
        print("Password must have at least 1 capital letter")
    elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
        print("Password must have at least 1 number")
    elif " " in password:
        print("Password must not contain spaces")
    elif not any(s in password for s in symbols):
        print("Password must contain at least one of " + symbols)
    else:
        print("ok buddy")

password = input("enter a password ")
passwordIsOk(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the nested `if` structure, you could use `any` to check if it contains any special symbol:

```
password = input("enter a password ")
def passwordIsOk (password):
    symbols = "$#%&*"
    if len (password) > 10:
        if any(i.isupper() for i in password):
            if any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
                if " " not in password:
                    if any(s in password for s in symbols):
                        passwordValid = True
                        print("ok buddy")
                     else:
                         print("Password must contain $#%&*")
                else:
                    print("Password must not contain spaces")
            else:
                print("Password must have at least 1 number")
        else:
            print("Password must have at least 1 capital letter")
    else:
        print("Password must be greater than 10 characters")
passwordIsOk(password)
```

It is arguably easier to read and it will print all the problems with the password if you invert and flatten out the if statements using the `passwordValid` flag like so:

```
password = input("enter a password ")
def passwordIsOk (password):
    passwordValid = True 
    symbols = "$#%&*"

    if len (password) <= 10:
        passwordValid = False
        print("Password must be greater than 10 characters")

    if not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
        passwordValid = False
        print("Password must have at least 1 capital letter")

    if not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
        passwordValid = False
        print("Password must have at least 1 number")

    if " " in password:
        passwordValid = False
        print("Password must not contain spaces")

    if not any(s in password for s in symbols):
        passwordValid = False
        print("Password must contain at least one of $#%&*")

    if passwordValid:
        print("ok buddy")

passwordIsOk(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common method in password validation are regular expressions.

```
# coding: utf-8
import re
from getpass import getpass 

def passwordIsOk(password):
    if len(password) < 10:
        print("Password must be greater than 10 characters")
    elif not re.search('[A-Z]',password):
        print("Password must have at least 1 capital letter")
    elif not re.search('[0-9]',password):
        print("Password must have at least 1 number")
    elif not re.search('[$#%&*]',password ):
        print("Password must contain at least one of $#%&*")
    elif " " in password:
        print("Password must not contain spaces")
    else:
        print("ok buddy")

pswd = getpass("Enter password: ")
passwordIsOk(pswd)
```